# NSURLConnection returns multiple php session ids

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, session, session-cookies

I have used NSURLConnection to connect to a web-service (rest) and get the response and cookies to use later.
But NSURLConnection returns multiple php session ids. This should be wrong, because when I test this using REST Easy (firefox rest app) it gives the follwing output.

```
Set-Cookie  PHPSESSID=1hk82sac38si2e58l2vvcduqh2; path=/; HttpOnly
```

But the NSURLConnection gives this,

```
@"PHPSESSID=f5p9ihq38sg4aeq3a98374s074; path=/; HttpOnly, PHPSESSID=e73ru08mtaf22t9rup33qjmkj5; path=/; HttpOnly, Loggedin=True;
```

(there are two PHPSESSIDs)

This is my code,

```
NSURL *nsurl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                   timeoutInterval:120.0];

request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
NSString *stringData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@&grant_type=%@&client_id=%@", username, password, grantType, clientId];
NSData *requestBodyData = [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I checked this with all cache policy values. But the output is same.

```
NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy = 0, 
NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData = 1, 
NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad = 2, 
NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad = 3,
```

How to get the correct php session id ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this snippet -

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = nil;
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@&grant_type=%@&client_id=%@", username, password, grantType, clientId];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setTimeoutInterval: 120];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```